# Advanced Routing with Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I want to use regular expressions inside my routes. I have an Products controller, but I want a different URL structure to access the products

- http://host/this/
- http://host/that/
- http://host/andthat/

These URLs should call a action in my controller (`Products:show_category(:category)`)

Is something like this possible?

```
match "(this|that|andthat)" => "products#show_category", :category => $1
```

the action should look like this

```
def show_category
  puts params[:category] # <-- "this" if http://host/this/ is called
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually tested it, but try out:

```
match ':category' => 'products#show_category', :constraints => { :category => /this|that|andthat/ }
```

Comment: Great, that works perfect! Thanks für the hint with the :constraints-Option

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this answers your question, but you could add a collection to routes.rb:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get :category1
    get :category2
    get :category3
  end
end
```

If you then run `rake routes`, you'll see that you have urls like `/products/category1` and `products/category2`. Category1, 2 and 3 can be defined in your controller as usual:

```
def category1
  #custom code here
end

def category2
  #custom code here
end    

def category3
  #custom code here
end
```

As I said, I'm not too sure if that's what you're looking to do, but hope that helps a bit!

Comment: I thought there is a smarter way to do that. I want to point all three urls pointing to the same action with the name of the category as a parameter. I concertize the question a little bit.

Comment: Sure, the suggestion above is perfect then!